# Decode Xdata stored in string in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, cdata

I have a string with CData encoded value in it.  How can I decode this properly.
Using XElement.Parse() throws an error because there is no root element.

```
var rawXml = GetFromExternalService();
var myValue = XElement.Parse(rawXml).Element("Description").Value;
```

The variable myValue is now `<![CDATA[some interesting stuff \r\n]]>`.   So in fact this is an error from the service, double encoding the value.  But I can't change that.

I could just strip the first 9 and the last 3 characters, but that just feels so wrong.

What is the best way to get the real value?

Kind regards
Damiaan

Comment: Can you show what's in `rawXml` variable?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky that is <Description>&lt;![CDATA[some interesting stuff \r\n]]&gt;</Description>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement.Parse("<root>"+myValue+"</root>").Value
```

Comment: Seems pretty clean.  Why would you choose this over stripping out the start and end of the string, as I suggested?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the exact characters used, just that it is double-encoded XML.